# java: data element change affects "unrelated" data structure

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures

I have a problem where I retrieve and element from a list (list1), and modify one of the parameters in the element and then add it to another list (list2). When I do this to the final item in list1, it will sometimes modify the parameters of the elements in list2.

This function is called once per generation, but it is not until about the 8th generation when I start to see this happen.  It has affect anywhere from 2 to 16 elements in list2.

Any ideas where my screw up might be? Here's a block of code I wrote to illustrate the problem.  The problem occurs in the section where I check count==0.

```
    public void sampleCode (List list) {
    List differentList = new ArrayList();
    Individual element;
    Individual differentelement;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        element = (Individual) list.get(i)  ;


        // does some checking to see if this meets criteria
        // this is sorta pseudo code
        if(probability == true) { 
            element.setDoMutation(true);
            count++;
        }
        //always add this element to differentList
                    //even if no changes are made to the element
        differentList.add(i,element);
    }
        //need to make sure one elements has mutation=true;
    if(count == 0) { 
        differentelement = (Individual) list.get((list.size()-1));

        //setting this element field changes the contents of
        //different list.
        differentelement.setDoMutation(true);
        differentList.set((list.size()-1), differentelement);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, a variable doesn't hold an object. It holds an object reference (i.e. a pointer to an object). Getting an object fom a list and putting it in another list doesn't make a copy of the object. Both lists simply have a pointer to the same object. So, of course, if you modify the contents of the object, both lists will have the object modified.

Side note: You should use parameterized types (i.e. `List<Individual>` rather than `List`), and avoid declaring variables at the beginning of your methods as you would do in C. Only declare a variable when you need it. This will make the code much clearer, and reduce the scope of your variables.

Comment: That doesn't explain to me how I can update the differentelement and it updates multiple values in differentlist.  At the point where differentelement is 'setting mutation to true' it is not associated yet with any element in the differentList...except that all elements originally came from "list" On your side note.. I do not disagree about parameterized types, but haven't yet figured out how to use them (it has been over a decade since I learned java, and almost as long since I last used it).  If ou can point me to a good tutorial on it, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: I hit enter too quickly...so this is an addition to above.  I am confused since even though differentelement points to a item from  "list", it should point to only one thing, so how it would update multiple elements is bewildering to me...?  I do not believe that it would (the way it is written) point to something that points to something that points to something.. would it?

Comment: @Kristin differentelement refers to only one object. Nevertheless this reference may be in your list several times. If you now change the object all references (in any list) show the new value (since each one references the same object).

Comment: I have looked at the object "numbers" in the debug mode, and they all look different. There are some expected copies, but the ones that are getting changed when setting "true" for different element are not those.

Comment: @Kristin: Read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html. Regarding pointers, I'll try to give you an analogy. Suppose you have an empty file in c:\ : file.txt. Open two explorer windows, and go to c:\ in these two explorer windows. file.txt is displayed in the two windows. Open file.txt from the first explorer window, add some text in the file and save the file. Now go to the second explorer window and open the file: it'll contain the text you just added. That's because the windows don't contain two copies of the file. They contain a pointer to a unique file.

Comment: OK, I have been lookking at my code. I have heavy manipulation of a list.  I go through the list in these ways (1) select for copy and "copy" a few items to a "next gen" list. then (2) select for reproduction and then copy results of the reproduction to the "next gen" list.  then (3) select 1 or 2 from the results of the reproduction to do mutation on, then copy the mutation to the "next gen" list.    Then, change generations, and use the "next gen" list as the current generation, and then it continues.

Comment: <continued> I had a stub function for the reproduction, where it sent back the same items put in for parameters. I changed those to "new" items, and now my problem is gone.  I am still not sure why. In the future, there will be manipulation of those items and so they will not be "new" objects.  Due to the extreme copy/list management that I am doing, what is the best way for to me clean it up?  You can see by my previous code snippet the way that I have been managing it thus far (create a new list, populate it, and return that list).

Comment: I just wanted to get back and close this loop.  There were a few problems... the biggest was that while I tried to do a copy, it wasn't  doing the deep copy that I needed.  The other was that I had another check which wasn't implemented yet.  I didn't handle that situation correctly, and so it propogated some "undesirable" elements.  Thank you for your patience whilest I got my Java hat back on (although it is probably still slightly askew!)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the block

```
    //need to make sure one elements has mutation=true;
    if(count == 0) { 
        differentelement = (Individual) list.get((list.size()-1));

        //setting this element field changes the contents of
        //different list.
        differentelement.setDoMutation(true);
        differentList.set((list.size()-1), differentelement);
    }
```

has to be inside the loop

```
for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

I suspect it has to be moved after the loop in order to work correctly.

Comment: My poor pseudo code is showing its weaknesses. In the "true" code that I wrote, it is outside of the for-loop.

Comment: @Kristin Therefore you should not show pseudo code but the true one. Errors, side effects and undefined behaviour mostly hide within the parts you don't show or which (in this case) are just wrong.

Comment: I tried to put the real-code here, but it was too long. I edited above to fix the error.. I'm more than willing to post the original, but wasn't sure etiquette-wise if changing the original post that much would be kosher.

Comment: @Kristin can you please show us the code where you populate the initial list or where you change that list. It seems that you inserted the same reference multiple times.

Comment: @Kristin:  You don't need to post the whole code.  What you need to post is a completely self-contained snippet that compiles, runs and when run exhibits the problem.  Cut out anything until you have the absolute minimum code that demonstrates the problem.  Often by doing this exercise you'll find the problem on your own.  See http://sscce.org.

Comment: @Mark: I responded with more "general" response above. I find it difficult to post long sections of code in these boxes as the response is limited,and code is not as short as I'd like it to be.  If you'd like to look at it, I have no problem sending it (or if you can tell me how to post it more easily).

Comment: @Mark: just saw your note about "self-contained snippet". I will work on that and see if things become self-evident.  I sure hope so. Thank you for the suggestion.